# Select input element by id using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on a box that has the following HTML code:

```
<li>
  <input id="mce-group[166]-166-0" type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[166][1] >
  <label for="mce-group[166]-166-0">I agree</label>
</li>
```

I've tried it all: id, name, xpath, text,...
Running something like this:

```
select_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mce-group[166]-166-0"]')
select_box.click()
```

I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="mce-group[166]-166-0" name="group[166][1]" type="checkbox"> could not be scrolled into view
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<input>` element associated with the text **I agree** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for=\"mce-group[166]-166-0\"]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for=\"mce-group[166]-166-0\"]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: @oscardvs Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Nope. I get the same error as in the begenning.```selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <label> could not be scrolled into view```